# Retrive array's first three element from document search based upon ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've an array inside document lets say user has `followedBy` array I want to find a user based on ID and then want to retrieve only first 3 elements of `followedBy`.

In picture you can see I have users collection and then inside user I've an array named as `followedBy`.

I need to search a user first based on Id and then to retrieve first 3 elements of array in a single query rather than fetch user first and get `followedBy` array having thousands of members inside it and then apply slice on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) you can use `$slice` into projection.

So you have to do:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "_id": your_id
},
{
  "followedBy": {
    "$slice": 3
  }
})
```

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4jY7IDZsfkQ) example.

Using `mongoose` is exactly the same query:

```js
YourModel.find({
    "id": your_id
  },
  {
    "followedBy": {
      "$slice": 3
    }
  })
.then(result => {
  // ...
}).catch(e => {})
```

Comment: thanks, it solved the problem, let me know if we can have super pagination here just like we do while fetching multiple records, or we have the only way to apply with slice? though slice can work as well. what you suggests?